# Script to remove characters

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a file with thousands of records pipe delimited with each field enclosed by quotes

```
"First Name"|"Last Name"|"address"|"City"|"State"|"Zip"
```

How would I write a batch script on windows to process the thousands records in a file?
Each line has one record on a line to make it look like the below

```
First Name|Last Name|address|City|State|Zip
```

Comment: When you say "process", what exactly do you mean?

Comment: Sorry. I mean i have a text file with the records in it. so essentially the batch file should read each record from a text file and strip the quotes out and store all the results in a text file.

Answer (score 1):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
DEL outfile.txt 2>nul
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN (pipedelims.txt) DO (
SET line=%%i
SET line=!line:"=!
>>outfile.txt ECHO(!line!
)
```

should do the job for you.

Comment: It's better to move the redirection out of the FOR-loop. And it removes exclamation marks and sometimes carets

Answer (score 1):

A bit more stable than the (also good) solution of Peter.

It can also handle lines with exclamation marks, carets,
this uses the toggling of the delayed expansion, as `set "line=%%i"` only works for all characters if delayed expansion is disabled, but for removing the quotes, the delayed expansion have to be enabled.

Lines beginning with ";" are normally removed by the default EOL-character, therefore I used a bit tricky construct to disable the EOL at all.

```
@echo off
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
(
  FOR /f delims^=^ EOL^= %%i IN (pipedelims.txt) DO (
    SET "line=%%i"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    SET "line=!line:"=!"
    ECHO(!line!
    endlocal
  )
) > outfile.txt
```

Comment: I don't understand this & it also doesn't work: `delims^=^EOF^= `. Simple `"delims="` works good. [Discussion](http://ss64.org/viewtopic.php?id=1544)

Comment: @Endoro - It was my typo, it has to be `EOL` not `EOF`. With only "delims=" you lose all lines beginning with a semicolon.

Answer (score 1):

Downloading GnuSed is an option:

```
@echo off
sed "s/\x22//g" "filein.txt" >"fileout.txt"
```

You also do the same thing using a VBS script.